# Timed out compiling Play 2.x - Java app (Heroku)

Tags: heroku, playframework, playframework-2.0

Every time I try to deploy the Play 2.0 default application on Heroku I see following message. What could be the possible cause of this delay ? How to resolve this ?

```
 !     Timed out compiling Play 2.x - Java app (15 minutes)
 !     See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/slug-compiler#time-limit

To git@heroku.com:lit-sea-4547.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:lit-sea-4547.git'
```

Comment: The slug compiler is slow at times, I've noticed. You can ask heroku support to increase the timeout limit for your app, though.

Comment: Same problem. Do you have many dependencies ?

Comment: @LimbSoup Can you provide any email ID or any mode to contact them quickly to increase build time.

Comment: Just open a support ticket. I did this the other day and they increased the limit within 10 minutes.